# Limit number of characters aggrid editable cell

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

how to limit number of characters for editable cell in ag-grid ?
I tried `maxLength` not working, also  `valueSetter` by returning only first 16 character not working.
Is there any way other than custom component

Comment: share running example to play around with it - plunk or stackblitz

Comment: @Paritosh here it is:
https://plnkr.co/edit/pWrSfQMTwc0OrlCPq2TZ?p=preview

Comment: OMG... why doesn't agGrid support this out of the box ?!  Someone has posted a CellRenderer for React which does support max-length here:   https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3572

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this plunk I've forked: [ag-grid: Limiting length while cell editing](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fg31HrBVosTQdLbjAmXZ?p=preview)

You can use `setDataValue` of `RowNode` object to set it's value. You can achieve it while handling `cellEditingStopped` event.

```
onCellEditingStopped: function (event) {
    let value = event.value.substr(0, 16);
    event.node.setDataValue(event.column.colId, value);
    console.log('cellEditingStopped');
}
```